# How to display list of users using AJAX Django that get updated while adding new users from admin page

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am trying to display a list of users that get updated using AJAX at the same time a new user is added using admin page .

Django 1.9 , Python 3.5 , I am working with a windows machine

My index.html

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for User in users %}
                <tr> 
                    <td>{{ User.username }}</td>
                    <td>{{ User.email }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

My views.py

```
def index(request):
context = RequestContext(request)
users=User.objects.all()
return render_to_response('index.html',{'users':users},context)
```

How to implement AJAX ? Please help me how to use ajax with Django and fulfill this simple task.

Comment: Your question is too broad, there are many ways to implement this. Also you should fix your indendation since Python is sensitive to indendation.

Comment: Could you explain me one way. I am new to ajax and Django.I wanted to display the name of users as table and it get updated as soon as a new user is added . just like we see notification. Hope you could help

Comment: @Selcuk if you know many methods could u pls help me out with one at least ? Commenting saying you know will not work rather helping will do . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow! 
If you simply wants to call Ajax using Django then You should try this:

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', locals())


def ajax_view(request):
    result = dict()
    data_list = []
    result['status'] = "success"
    for u in User.objects.all():
        list_of_user = {'email': u.email, 'first_name': u.first_name}
        data_list.append(list_of_user)
    result['data'] = data_list

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type='application/x-json')
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="/path/to/js/my_ajax.js"></script>
<table class="myTable">
        <thead>        
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
</table>
```

**my_ajax.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/ajax/',
        success: function (result) {

            if (result.status == "success") {
                if (result['data']) {
                    jQuery.each(result['data'], function (i, val) {

                        $('.myTable').append(
                            '<tr><td id="first_name">'+val['first_name']+'</td>' +
                            '<td id="email">'+val['email']+'</td></tr>');

                    });
                }
            }
        }
    })

});
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^ajax/$', ajax_view, name='temp'), # Function calls ajax
url(r'^index/$', index, name='index'),  # main function redirect to index.html
```

This will call your ajax and get User's data.

Comment: It is simply downloading the user data . 
I wanted to display the name of users as table and it get updated as soon as a new user is added . just like we see notification. Hope you could help

Comment: There is no real time sync