# How could i display search result based on filtered value provided by user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have developed filter system where it provides 3 options such as property type, number of rooms, and maximum price. Every time they select filter options the user will get their search result instantly. For example, if a user has selected property type of Apartment and number of rooms as 4 and maximum price of 12000 then the user will get those rents whose property type is apartment with 4 rooms of 12000 mark. I developed the front-end part with React.js and could fetch user selected data successfully. I have also passed data to ajax but I have no idea how should I display the search results based on filtered value provided by user with no page loading.

**Ajax code**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/filter/space/',
  data{property:propertySelectedValue, room:roomSelectedValue, price:maxPrice},
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data['fields']);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.error("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
  },
});
```

**Views.py**

```
class FilterSpace(View):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        property = request.GET.get('property',None)
        room = request.GET.get('room', None)
        price = request.GET.get('price', None)
        rental = Rental.objects.all()
        if room:
            rental = rental.filter(room=room)
            print('rental',rental)
        if price:
            rental = rental.filter(price__lte=price)
        if property:
            rental = rental.filter(property=property)
        rental_json =  serializers.serialize('json',rental)
        print('rental_json',rental_json)
        return HttpResponse(rental_json,content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display list of users using AJAX Django that get updated while adding new users from admin page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333163/how-to-display-list-of-users-using-ajax-django-that-get-updated-while-adding-new)

Comment: explain: with no page loading. What do you try to solve?

Comment: Have you thought about sending the request to the back-end via an API? You would send the request, receive the response and update the page correspondingly. That way you don't need to reload the page.

Comment: I have not tried that because i wanted to upload multiple images at the same time which will be very difficult if i used an REST API.

Comment: I *think* the question is more of javascript than Django. You are on the right path. You are requesting data from Django, and django is returning with a JSON  object. Your code seems right (have not tested). Then, in your `success` function, you need to **DO** something with that data. Take a look at http://datatables.net/ It is a great tool that can do a lot of the heavy lifting for you. The question for you is: how do you want to display the information?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might consider doing is rendering the html to a string ([django - render_to_string not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958543/django-render-to-string-not-working)) on the server side and send that back in an ajax response along with the data. then replace the html where the list is contained with that rendered by the server.

Django:

```
def get_list(request, *args, **kwargs):
    items = Items.objects.filter(...)
    html = ""
    items = [] # actual data
    context = {
        "item_list": items,
        ...
    }

    for item in items:
        html = html + render_to_string(list_html_template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        items.append(item.to_json()) # You have to define this if you want it.

    return JsonResponse({
        "list_html": html,
        "items_data": itmes
    })
```

Template (list_html_template):

```
{% for item in item_list %}
<!-- render item here... -->
{% endfor %}
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url_for_get_list_view",
    dataType: "json",
    ...
    success: function(json) {
        $(list_container).html(json.list_html); // Will replace any current html in this container (i.e. refresh the list).
        /* You can also do stuff with json.items_data if you want. */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for efficiency in the python you should find the way to filter once with all the parameters instead of filter the filtered of the filtered, but this is not essential to see result.

inside `success: function(data){` you should use jQuery to put `data` into the page, you might start with something like

```
function data2html(data) {
   ...// use .map and .join
}
$("#divid").append(data2html(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear up your view by doing something like this:

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        results = Rental.objects.filter(**request.GET)
        return serializers.serialize('json', results)
```

and when you get the data back in your AJAX request, in the `success` part just clear your table and iterate over the results and append rows to the now empty table with your data.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, its clearer to have the logic and rendering taking place in django using AJAX to retrieve and place the rendered html. Here is a sketch of the code

Here is the view that passes the set of rentals to an html template

> ```
> def ajax_rental_search(request):
>     search_text = 'missing'
>
>     if request.method == "GET":
>         search_text = request.GET.get("search_text", "missing")
>
>     # DEBUG: THIS CAN CHECK THE CONNECTION
>     # return HttpResponse('SERVER RESPONSE: search_text: ' + search_text)
>
>     if search_text != 'missing':
>         rentals = Rental.objects # add filters etc. 
>
>     context = {
>         "rentals": rentals
>     }
>
>     return render(request, "rentals_search_response.html", context)
> ```

Here is the key part, the jquery, ajax request:

> ```
>     function rentalSearch() {
>         const search_text = content_search_input');
>
>         $.ajax({
>             type: "GET",
>             url: < rental_search_url >,
>             data: {
>                 'search_text': search_text,
>             },
>             success: function (serverResponse_data) {
>                 // console.log('search success: ' + serverResponse_data);
>                 $('#rentals_content').html(serverResponse_data);  
>                 // rentals_content is an existing div on page
>             },
>             error: function (serverResponse_data) {
>                 console.log('error:' + serverResponse_data)
>             }
>         });
>     }
> ```

Then you can style the displayed rentals as  you wish knowing that they are all going to passed to the sub template.
Thats it