# django render_to_string missing information

Tags: django

Why my email (in the body part) does not contain the message?

Here is my code:

```
message = render_to_string('contact_template.txt', {'contact_name':   contact_name, 'contact_email': contact_email, 'form_content': content}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
email = EmailMessage("New contact form submission", message, "annadrybulska@gmail.com" +'', ['annadrybulska@gmail.com'], headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email })
email.send()
```

My template (contact_template.txt), (all my received emails contained this, but no message) :

```
Contact Name:


Email:


Content:
```

and my views:(I have to say it is intimidating...)

```
from polls.forms import ContactForm
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.template import Context, Template, RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template.loader import render_to_string, get_template

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")

def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    # logic!
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name', '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email', '')
            content = request.POST.get('content', '')         
        
            message = render_to_string('contact_template.txt', {'contact_name': contact_name, 'contact_email': contact_email, 'form_content': content}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        
            email = EmailMessage("New contact form submission", message, "annadrybulska@gmail.com" +'', ['annadrybulska@gmail.com'], headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email })
            email.send()
            return redirect('contact')

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form_class,})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Anna. Would you mind posting your template + view for this? The code should be minimally complete for anyone to reproduce the same problem

Comment: oh thank you for answering (couldn't be happier), her it is:

Comment: Where? Still waiting. You can edit your main question to post it

Comment: @MohitC I'm not so quick...sorry

Comment: @AnnaDrybulska The code you post shouldn't work. I'm assuming you are missing a level of indenting starting from the `# Logic` line.

Comment: @MohitC sorry,you are right,  it is indented(in original file) and it send email, will edit that immediately

Comment: You do use context variables in your template, don't you? Like that: `Contact Name: {{ contact_name }}`

Comment: brilliant :) thank you @StanislavShabalin

Answer (score 25):

For clarity purposes, I would try to limit yourself to a maximum numbers of characters per line. This makes reading the [`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) line very hard, and makes it even harder to find errors.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

context = {
    'contact_name': contact_name, 
    'contact_email': contact_email, 
    'form_content': content
}
message = render_to_string('contact_template.txt', context, 
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It seems you are missing locations in the template where the variables are to be printed. You define the following variables:

- 'contact_name'
- 'contact_email'
- 'form_content'

They are however not used in the template. Example:

```
Contact Name:
{{ contact_name }}

Email:
{{ contact_email }}

Content:
{{ form_content }}
```

Comment: Note: `RemovedInDjango110Warning: The context_instance argument of render_to_string is deprecated`.