# POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/notifications/ajax/ 403 (FORBIDDEN)//using ajax+django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

why am I getting this error, I think I have correct ajax functions, I set my urls right...please, any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<div id='notificationsLoader'>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".notification-toggle").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"{% url 'get_notifications_ajax' %}",
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
      },
      success: function(data){
        $("#notificationsLoader").html('<h3>notifications</h3>');
        $(data.notifications).each(function(){
          $("notificationsLoader").append(this + "<br/>")
        })
        console.log(data.notifications);
      },
      error: function(rs, e){
        console.log(rs);
        console.log(e);
      }


    })
  })
})
</script>
```

In **views.py**

```
@login_required
def get_notifications_ajax(request):
    notification = Notification.objects.get(id=id)
    notes =[]

    for note in notifications:
        notes.append(str(note))
    data={
        "notifications":notes
        }
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

and in **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += patterns('notifications.views',
    url(r'^notifications/$', 'all', name='notifications_all'),
    url(r'^notifications/ajax/$', 'get_notifications_ajax', name='get_notifications_ajax'),
    url(r'^notifications/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'read', name='notifications_read'),

)
```

I've tried changing allowing host in my **settings.py** but it won't work. I'm almost sure the code is correct because I'm following a tutorial and with this code instructor does it without a problem. Thank you,

**Full Error**

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/notifications/ajax/ 403 (FORBIDDEN)>
>   ERROR)send @ jquery.min.js:4m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous
>   function) @ (index):359m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3r.handle @
>   jquery.min.js:3

Comment: Do u really need method POST, Just refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35340286/5633503, Hope this will help

Comment: @Kjjassy I think so, no? I'm following a tutorial, and the instructor had put one as well https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/srvup-membership/blob/943b18cd078618ad44f1f2c47d241cedeea4dbfe/src/templates/base.html...even without POST same error appears anyway.

Comment: @mika you have send me a wrong link :)

Comment: @Kjjassy opps sorry https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/srvup-membership/blob/943b18cd078618ad44f1f2c47d241cedeea4dbfe/src/templates/base.html

Comment: I have looked it, it seems you are following this tutorial steps right, try to debug and print errors, and download https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/srvup-membership/tree/943b18cd078618ad44f1f2c47d241cedeea4dbfe this and cross verify your code, that's what i can do man.

Comment: @Kjjassy thanks man, the error is occuring in console. When I click notification button, it should list notifications but instead in a console, I get 
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/notifications/ajax/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: @Kjjassy I've uploaded the errors, do you mind taking a look at this?I'm stuck in this step for a while.

Comment: From where you get the `id` in your python view (in `id=id`)?

Comment: @doru I get it from models.py/it gets imported....but I don't think that's relevant to the problem I'm having or is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is using a `csrf_token` context variable that I'm guessing you havent set up, more likely you wanted to use the django template tag for the token

```
  url:"{% url 'get_notifications_ajax' %}",
  data: {
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{% csrf_token %}",
  },
```

Other than that, a 500 error is a server error, when debugging and developing you should be doing so with the `DEBUG` setting set to true to get more informative errors.

Comment: thank you but now I get 403(Forbidden) which I think is from csrf, and I set my debug=true in my settings.py

Comment: @mikebraa - You should update your question to include the information you get from the error now

Comment: ok, so I should use csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{% csrf_token %}" over         csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}"?? because I'm doing a django tutorial(got stuck here) and the instructor is using {{csrf_token}}

Comment: @mikebraa - I have no idea why the instructor is using it there, they may include it in a view for whatever reason. [They use the correct syntax everywhere else](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/srvup-membership/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=csrf_token)

Comment: I see...I guess I should update the question then. thank you